# Relative URLs in javascript/jquery & rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a URL like this for each record:

```
http://localhost:3000/items/3/stuff.json
http://localhost:3000/items/1/stuff.json
http://localhost:3000/items/4/stuff.json
http://localhost:3000/items/9/stuff.json
```

when on a page such as `http://localhost:3000/items/3/`, the linked JavaScript file has code like this:

```
$.getJSON(document.URL+'/stuff.json');
```

this allows me to grab the JSON file without worrying about the record ID number.

The problem arises on a URLs such as:

```
http://localhost:3000/items/3/news
http://localhost:3000/items/3/photos
```

as this:

```
$.getJSON(document.URL+'/stuff.json');
```

will be looking for:

```
http://localhost:3000/items/3/news/stuff.json
```

which of course, does not exist.

Any ideas for how I should solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$.getJSON("../stuff.json", function(data){



});
```

if current url is "http://localhost:3000/items/3/anything"

EDIT:

```
$.getJSON(document.URL.match(/\/items\/\d+\//) + "stuff.json", function(data){



});
```

If all the urls are of the form `http://host/items/id/anything`

Comment: its in 1 js file though - so this would break it on the other pages (non-anything) wouldnt it?

Comment: Yes. It will break. I have updated the answer with another suggestion. Please check it.

Comment: changed it to /\/companies\/\d+/ and /stuff to make it work on all pages

Answer (score 0):

If this JS is rendered at all by Rails (i.e. it's not something that comes from the Asset Pipeline) then you can use the routing helpers, like this:

```
<script>$.getJSON("<%= item_news_stuff_path(3, :format => :json) %>")</script>
```

This would generate a relative-to-root path to the resource, building the route up correctly.

Comment: unfortunately, it is in the asset pipeline currently